# Sci-Fi About Colonizing Planet With Dumb Humans

Tags: story-identification, novel, space-colonization

The beginning of the book is a little fuzzy to me but here goes. Humanity is intergalactic sometime far in the future. The main character from what I can remember isn't one of the rich elite, but he talks to one of them and is given a ship with people to go colonize a world. Something happens to the hibernating colonizers and the main character is the only one unaffected. So he has to educate the now idiotic colonizers and he goes back into hibernation for a few hundred years from time to time and the society continues to grow, eventually becoming very advanced after a few thousand years. The society worships the ship where he hibernates and reveers him as a God on his occasional appearances. Lmao I can remember all these details but not the name of the book. I borrowed it from my library around 2018 and the book was a paperback with a colorful and faded looking cover so it might be an older novel.

Comment: Not just interstellar but *intergalactic*, as in, more than one galaxy? Has mankind "merely" colonized some of the Milky Way's satellite galaxies such as the Magellanic Clouds, or have they gone all the way to Andromeda? Was this vast expansion of humanity important to the story?

Comment: I don't believe so, I can't remember much of the backstory but the story was mainly focused on the exploration and development of that one planet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like *[The Worthing Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Worthing_Saga)* by Orson Scott Card.  Jason Worthing, a telepath, is piloting a sleeper ship to found a colony when he is attacked.  He survives, but the cryogenic storage is ruined, leaving him with healthy bodies but no minds.  He must bring the colonists to life, a couple here, a couple there, slowly, giving him time to educate them.  The further along the new civilization grows, the less his oversight is required, so he spends more time hibernating in his ship and, yes, because of his short appearances over time the colonists treat him as a deity.

[image: The Worthing Saga cover art]

Comment: If accepted, this would be a duplicate of [Book I read back in the 90’s, about a boy who became a space pilot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275398/book-i-read-back-in-the-90-s-about-a-boy-who-became-a-space-pilot) and probably others.

Comment: And the setting is an **intergalactic** human civilization? Human beings ravel between galaxies on sleeper ships??

Comment: this sounds exactly as how I remember it thank you very much

Comment: @user14111 They have this thing called SOMEC that allows the rich elite to sleep thru the centuries. Staying awake for a year, or a month every century. Skimming thru time. All of the rich elite do this... technological progression has all but stagnated, But on the plus side it makes a couple of centuries or more of space travel not have an impact on ones social life as long as you remain 'in sync'...